# PHP fopen from another .php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to print out content of a php file.

Here is how I was trying to do print it.

```
$filename = "read.php";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
print $contents;
```

The method above I found didn't work. It didn't print anything on the screen.

Can someone tell me how to fix this.

Also I want to know how to write to a .php and and save it.

Note: I'm not trying to print the output of the php file. Example: If `read.php` say `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` I want to print out `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` Not just "Hello World"

Comment: Did you check that the output was actually empty, and not just being interpreted as HTML by your browser? (Try View Source, add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to your code, or use `echo htmlspecialchars($contents);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just ?

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('read.php'));
```

Comment: What if the file is interpreted ?

Comment: @LaurentWartel, It will **not** be interpreted.

Answer (score -1):

The `file()` reads the file line by line in an array and an `array_map` is done on the array elements with `htmlentities` as the call-back function.

```
<?php
foreach(array_map('htmlentities',file('read.php')) as $line)
{
    echo $line."<br>";
}
```